# como consumir una api desde larave usando axios

Tags: laravel, api, axios

Construí una api en node.js y ahora usando laravel (en el cual integre metronic) necesito consumirla y quisiera usar axios para esto, se que laravel por defecto incluye este paquete, pero no se como integrarlo correctamente.

Comment: Ya leíste la documentación?

Comment: esperaba algo mas de orientacion

Comment: Trata algo y entonces sabremos desde que punto ayudarte

Comment: Laravel es un framework Php, y axios una librería javascript. Laravel no incluye por defecto axios, opcionalmente puedes instalarle el paquete `laravel/ui`, que trae algunos presets de javascript y css que podrás luego instalar y compilar. No se entiende si quieres consumir una api externa desde el frontend de tu aplicación laravel, pues axios no funciona en php. También, como ya te mencionaron, al no agregar a la pregunta lo que llevas hecho, no hay un punto de partida concreto para responder.